# Not operation on a regex using findstr won't work

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have a file test_file.txt

```
test
test_1
```

I use findstr to look for a string

```
C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop>findstr /R /C:"test" test_file.txt
test
test_1
```

If I look for a string using underscore, it works

```
C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop>findstr /R /C:"test[_]" test_file.txt
test_1
```

However, if I look for a string NOT using underscore, I've got nothing.

```
C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop>findstr /R /C:"test[^_]" test_file.txt

C:\Users\Rafael\Desktop>
```

Using regex101.com:

[image: Test working using regex101.com]

Why? Is there a solution?

Comment: use `\b` instead of `[^_]` .. or maybe `(?!_)`

Comment: Same thing. Blank response.

Comment: Note that the regular expression support in findstr is both limited and very out of date.  Don't expect it to support everything that works on regex101.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test[^_]` is a wrong regexp to catch the line with only `test` because `[^_]` *needs* a character but there's none: the string ends right after `test`.

Word boundary special characters should be used:

```
findstr /r /c:"\<test\>" inputfile.txt
```